# How to repair corrupted table

Tags: mysql

I have the `mysql`table called *Sample*. I have edited the file `/var/lib/mysql/Sample.MYI` with some values. Now check TABLE Sample query shows as

> Incorrect key file for table 'Sample'; try to repair it

To repair this, i have tried using the following command `myisamchk -r Sample.MYI`. but the result is "myisamchk:

> error: Got error 140 when trying to recreate indexfile MyISAM-table `Sample.MYI` is not fixed because of errors".

Now how to repair this table ?

Answer (score 20):

Just in case you don't have backup, don't have the original file and cannot redownload it, here are some links that might help you:

http://www.felipecruz.com/repair-mysql-database.php
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html (see also links at the bottom of this page)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,362974,362974

The following command will recreate .myi files from scratch:

```
REPAIR TABLE tablename USE_FRM
```

[image]Be careful with this though, this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html says:

> Use the USE_FRM option only if you cannot use regular REPAIR modes! Telling the server to ignore the .MYI file makes important table metadata stored in the .MYI unavailable to the repair process, which can have deleterious consequences:[.....]

And finally how to redo this in different ways:

http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/foot.htm

Comment: @ssbecse, which link did you try and what solution worked for you?

Comment: http://www.felipecruz.com/repair-mysql-database.php and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html.In these have the option called "REPAIR TABLE tablename USE_FRM;" .its working fine

Comment: @ssbecse, cool MySQL doesn't really repair anything though, it just recreates the .myi files from scratch. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem :-).

Comment: @ssbecse, repairing always holds a danger of dataloss, because MySQL has to make a guess what data might have been in the place where there is now corrupted data. If it guesses wrong, it might just put completly wrong data in. E.g. suppose MySQL reports your .myi files is wrong, but that's really not true, and your .myi is fine, but your data file is corrupt. Then MySQL might recreate an .myi file and overwite a good file based on a corrupt data file. No worries, always backup first. Try it and see if it works, if it doesn't restore from backup and try something else.

Comment: In my application, periodically data updated in MySQL table.how to take the backup upto tables gets corrupted.

Comment: @ssbecse, just google for MySQL backup(first link): http://www.google.nl/search?q=mysql%20backup&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:nl:official&client=firefox-a&source=hp&channel=np, there's lots of ways. Make sure you store the backup on a different disk!

Comment: This worked for me when I had REPAIR issues that would not go in the normal way

Answer (score 12):

Check the status of the corrupted table

```
check table tablename;
```

e.g

```
mysql> check table realtime_clicks_update;
+--------------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table                          | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| logdata.realtime_clicks_update | check | status   | OK       |
+--------------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

If status is not OK then repair it using following command

```
mysql> repair table tablename;
```

Answer (score 8):

Why did you edit the `.MYI` file? You're not supposed to do that.

Restore from backups then re-apply the changes in the proper fashion.

Answer (score 0):

put back the original Sample.MYI file :)

Comment: in my application,i have do negative testing.ie,if table gets corrupted, my code should take care to repair that table ...

Comment: @ssbecse, that's a stupid notion. That's what backups are for. And besides the .myi format is a moving target, MySQL never promised they will not change the layout of that file.

Comment: that will only work when the underlying table has not changed at all, not a very likely scenario in production.

Comment: Johan, the idea was to use the backup - which, usually is not the files itself.