# piwik error table piwik piwik_log_visit is marked as crashed and last automatic repair failed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, matomo, repair

I got this error on my piwik accounts after my server went down. I have tried to repair the table with these commands in phpmyAdmin

```
REPAIR TABLE piwik_log_visit;
REPAIR TABLE piwik_log_link_visit_action;
```

It's still not working and giving the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to repair corrupted table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177246/how-to-repair-corrupted-table)