# Recover mysql data from .ibd file

Tags: mysql, database, backup, recovery

My database files are corrupted somehow!!

I have got **only the .ibd (eg: customers.ibd) files** of the table names in the MySql data directory, there is no other file extension of the table is **available (eg: .frm or .myd)**.

Is there any ways to *recover* the data of the database??

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @bernhardh Unfortunately I could not recover any data from that drive. However if you have `ibdata1` file from the parent data directory and those files and try running `recover [databasename]` and see what happens. Check this solution if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177246/how-to-repair-corrupted-table